# WebBrowser .NET Control - how to check if previously event has finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-controls

At the beginning I would like to apologize because title of question may be misleading but I couldn't find better way to name it.

Here's the problem:

I have application which reads account infos from file and then based on that, it is suppose to log-in into website - everything was working great when each step was executed via DocumentComplete event of WebBrowser but I wanted to re-write the code so it would look better and be easier to modify and upgrade.

Right now, in order to login I have to get token from website and then send postdata with login,password and token, so I wanted to create two methods:

a)GetToken
b)LogIn

Right now they look like: (Tried solution given by user itsme86 but still doesn't work)

```
       public void GetToken()
                {
                    browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AfterLoadingTokenSite);
                    browser.Navigate("https://somewebsite.com");
                }

    private void AfterLoadingTokenSite(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                //here code which parse HTML in order to find token - works perfectly

            }

            public void LogIn()
            {
                string postData = string.Format("_mToken={0}&userID={1}&userPW={2}", userToken, userID, userPW);
                UTF8Encoding standardEncoding = new UTF8Encoding();

                browser.DocumentCompleted -= new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AfterLoadingTokenSite);
                browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AfterLoadingLoginSite);

                browser.Navigate("https://www.somewebsite.com/login/", "", standardEncoding.GetBytes(postData), "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
            }

            private void AfterLoadingLoginSite(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Url.AbsolutePath != (sender as WebBrowser).Url.AbsolutePath)
                    return; 
                else if (browser.DocumentText.Contains("Logged in as"))
                {
                    _logged = true;
                }
            }


And on FormLoad event I wanted to load all accounts from file to List and then do something like that:

    LoadAccountsFromFile();
    if (loadedAccounts)
    {
         foreach (Account n in AllAccounts)
         {
              n.GetToken();
              n.LogIn();
         }
    }
```

But that doesn't work because as far as I understand there is no default mechanism for WebControl to wait for previous event to finish before launching next one so my code goes straight to LogIn without waiting for AfterLoadingTokenSite() to finish.

So my question is how I can prevent it?

It has to be done in .NET 3.5.

Comment: You can use an `AutoResetEvent` to synchronize. `Account.Login()` would block (via `AutoResetEvent.WaitOne()`) until `Account.GetToken()` calls `AutoResetEvent.Set()` (from the `DocumentCompleted` event handler like you have it set up now). You can read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That doesn't work, the WaitOne() call will deadlock the program since it prevents the DocumentCompleted event from being raised.  Never block the UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to implement that right after itsme86's comment but that doesn't work. (Updated question with updated code)

Do You guys have any other idea?

Comment: Changing your question to include a suggestion that doesn't work isn't so good. Either show both versions or just show the original code. Then you can maybe get suggestions based on your original code without the confusion of something you know doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, thank You.
Deleted updated code and kept it original with note that I already tried itsme86 method.